# Synaptic touchpad right-click not working

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, synaptics

I'm having the same problem as in previous Ubuntu versions. The workaround to the problem for 11.10 was to use https://launchpad.net/~sergio91pt/+archive/synaptics+clickpads, but for 12.04 I haven't found a solution that works.

---

HP 210-1095tu netbook
Atom n450
RAM 2GB

Answer (score 4):

I had that problem (touchpad right click not working) with ubuntu 12.04, and found this link very useful:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Buttonless_TouchPads_.28aka_ClickPads.29

In my case, all I had to do was to define the area of the right button, adding the line

```
Option "SoftButtonAreas"  "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
```

to the configuration file as explained there.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and this workaround has no side effects.  I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04 with gnome-shell 3.4 on it (for that fast, bare bones gui without all the pre-loaded packages).  **With two fingers, double tap the touchpad and stay down on the second tap then let up one finger** to move the mouse pointer.  Note: must have *Enable mouse clicks with touchpad* option checked in System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad.  On my machine it seems to behave as though the right mouse button was held down.  When you let up the second finger, whatever is being pointed at by the mouse pointer gets right clicked.  No side effects that I can find.  I'd still rather my right mouse button work but I'll take it for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use below command if you have followed the `echo options psmouse proto=exps > /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.modprobe` this command.

Please don't use above command or if you have been used it so below there  is a solution to revert back

`sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.modprobe
sudo reboot`

Comment: Your answer is confusing. Could you please edit it to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo su
echo options psmouse proto=exps > /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.modprobe
reboot
```

This does have some side effects: you may lose other touchpad features, like two-finger scrolling.  In fact, this removes the touchpad tab from the mouse config settings window.

Comment: Tried this, and it didn't restore the right-click on a Samsung 900X3A.

Comment: I use the command you wrote but all the touchpad functions are gone, How can I recover it?