# Touch Pad is detected as a generic mouse device in 12.04

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

My touchpad seems like PS/2Generic Mouse device with the output xinput. I cannot set it correctly albeit I gave some tries. In addition its multitouch functions do not work becasue of this detection issue.

Here is the output of xinput list

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ ...
```

In addition, the problem occured after I tried to activate right click of my touch pad with following command from [Synaptic touchpad right-click not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131872/synaptic-touchpad-right-click-not-working/134518#comment335773_134518)

```
sudo su
echo options psmouse proto=exps > /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.modprobe
reboot
```

How can I check all the problems out and get my touchpad working all correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I totally remove psmouse by following commands

```
sudo dkms remove --all  psmouse/alps-dst-0.4
```

and I remove the config file;

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse*
```

and my touchpad came into life